# Showing onboarding Viewcontroller once

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where I am showing an onboarding screen. I now want the onboarding screen to show just once throughout the app life except the user delets and reinstall. That is the user can only see the onboarding once and when the user opens the app again, the user should be able to see the main page. I tried using Userdefaults in the `AppDelegate` `didFinishLauchWithOptions` but I could not get it to work well.

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didSee") {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "didSee")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "CategorySB", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.CATEGORY_VC)
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I have the onboarding in its own StoryBoard too `OnBoardingSB` and in the main app project, I made the `Main Interface` is the `OnBoardingSB`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: where you are setting didSee value to true?

Comment: Before assigning anything to window. You have to instantiate it. Like window = UIWindow(). Then assign properties to it. As because window is null during the appDidFinishlaunching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set it to `true`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didSee")
```

Comment: Thanks. I would really want to meet the person behind this account. I am very grateful

Comment: But if OP sets to `true` every time, won't the view controller be presented every time as well? I am guessing the setting to `true` would override the previous `false`. Is there something I don't see?

Comment: note **!** here **!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didSee")** , default value for any bool is false if the key doesn't exist

Comment: I know that, but where would you set it to `true` so that it only happens once in the lifetime of the app?

Comment: and that what the op wants once per app setup

Comment: Can you answer me where you would put this line of code? Every place I can think of (`didFinishLaunchingApp`, etc.) it is presented every time the app is killed and reopened.

Comment: please look to the code in question carefully only replace false to true in it

Comment: I see what you did there now. You only present the controller when the value is `nil` or `false`. Thank you, had my logic swapped.

Comment: Hi, you could help check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260589/displaying-a-uiviewcontroller-embeded-in-a-navigation-controller-with-button-tap thanks