# displaying a uiviewcontroller embeded in a navigation controller with button tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to present a viewcontroller embedded in a navigation caontroller by tapping a button. Everytime I tap the button the app crashes saying 
`Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x11320f420) to`

**my code to display the Viewcontroller**

```
@IBAction func skipButtonTapped(_ : UIButton) {
    let viewController: CategoryVC = UIStoryboard(name: "CategorySB", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.CATEGORY_VC) as! CategoryVC
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

any help thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209626/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: it is not a duplicate and this is by tiggering a navigationVC via button tapped

Comment: The idea on those duplicate target link can be applied to your case since the basic idea is the same, you force cast navigation controller to another view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let nav = UIStoryboard(name: "CategorySB", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.CATEGORY_VC) as! UINavigationController 
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

//

if you wan to access root

```
if let cat = nav.topViewController as? CategoryVC {

}
```

Comment: the displayed viewcontroller seems different from the standard loading of the viewcontroller without instantiating it with the button

Comment: the top bar title is blurry

Comment: with `if let cat = nav.topViewController as? CategoryVC {
self.present(cat, animated: true, completion: nil)
}` I got the error`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller`

Comment: if you want to present it give it id and instantiate it then present , if you want to present it inside the navigation then set identifier as in answer for the navigation and load it , you can change the color of the navigation bar to anything

Comment: sorry but I do not understand

Comment: tell me shortly what you want to do

Comment: I have decided to set the uinavigation properties in my didfinishLauchWith options so the answer is good now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179756/discussion-between-king-and-sh-khan).